# How to initialize an array field inside a structure?

Tags: c

So I have an exercice that asks me to define a structure that has 2 fields: one field to store an array of an already defined size, one field to store the length of the array. Then I have to define a function that should initialize the 2 fields in the structure, and another funciton that prints the 2 fields 
I'm just a beginner in programming, here's my attempt to write the code, but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define SIZE 10
typedef struct stdata data{
    int array[SIZE];
    int length;
}
void initialize (int array[],int length){
    data p;
    p.array[SIZE]=array;
    p.length=length;
}
void print(data p){
    printf("%d %d ",p.array,p.length);
}
```

Comment: Hint: Check the data type of `p.array`...

Comment: `p.array[SIZE]` is off  by one, C uses 0-based indexing. You cannot assign arrays, moreover.

Comment: How can I assign an array to a field in a struct ?

Comment: BTW `typedef struct stdata data{ ... }` --> `typedef struct stdata { ... } data;`

Comment: You can't, you have to assign element by element, using a loop.

Comment: Also `data p;` is local variable inside function `initialize`.

Comment: Can anybody please write the entire code I have an exam tomorrow I would really appreciate it

Comment: @Adam it is not about the exam, you have to love programming otherwise you will be stuck in a job that is not satisfying for you. Passing the exam is no the key. Also consider the comments to make your code 100% correct. The machine will never let you down.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/gkkcU6)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two different ways both are correct:

Method 1:

```
memcpy(p.array, array, sizeof(int) * length);
```

Method 2: (using a loop)

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) p.array[i] = array[i];
```